# Adding Custom UIView to iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, icarousel

I am having trouble while adding Views to my iCarousel "viewForItemAtIndex" method

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{


UIView *sub = nil;
//iCarousel *temp;

//create new view if no view is available for recycling
if (view == nil)
{
    UIViewController * viewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UIidentifier"];
    view = [viewController.view viewWithTag:20];

    CGRect  Frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + 100, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    view.frame = Frame;
}

UILabel *label=(UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:23];
label.text = [[listOfAnimalsNames objectAtIndex:index]nameOfTheCompanie];
return view;

}
```

I want to display a UIView "mockUp" and fill the labels with some data by using the "index" of the iCarousel, I have created my own UIViewController that contains the "mockup" UIView. The thing is that when I call this UIView (as in the code) nothing happens. (I use the reloadData method after loading data)

Comment: Try view.bounds instead of view.frame when you set up view frame.

Answer (score 0):

Why does each view need its own ViewController? They should all be controlled by whatever is controlling the iCarousel view (or at least its data source). Also, the UILabel should be instantiated only once.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIView *sub = nil;

if (view == nil)
{
    view = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...);
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(...)];
    [view addSubview:label];
}

label.text = [[listOfAnimalsNames objectAtIndex:index]nameOfTheCompanie];
return view;
}
```

Comment: Because I want to design/edit the "mockUp" graphically in the storyBoard and I don't know another way to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, since iCarousel apparently does not provide a proper interface with Storyboard, there's no pain-free way to do that. A lot of the time, what I'll do is open up a UIView in storyboard and design it graphically, and then transfer the coordinates and frames over to the code.

Comment: Now it's working but I don't know why the view has an offset of 1/2 view.width and 1/2 view.heigth (I can't upload an image since i have not reputation enough)

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange. Must be a frame origin issue. Is the view scrunched up? (i.e. does it look like the width and height are smaller than they should be)

Comment: Why are you using `view.frame.origin.y + 100`?

Comment: Sorry, it was just debbuging stuff n order to move the view but it doesn't work :/